# How to grep "block" strings out of a weird file

Tags: text-processing, aix

Command on AIX is:

```
[root@hx042:/home/user1]$ lqueryvg -Atp hdiskpower13
0516-1396 lqueryvg: The physical volume hdiskpower13, was not found in the system database. 
Max LVs:        256 
PP Size:        30 
Free PPs:       0 
LV count:       3 
PV count:       3 
Total VGDAs:    3 
Conc Allowed:   0 
MAX PPs per PV: 1016 
MAX PVs:        32 
Quorum (disk):  1 
Quorum (dd):    ??????? 
Auto Varyon ?:  1 
Conc Autovaryon 0 
Varied on Conc: 0
Logical:        00f62b5c00004c000000014de7f073b1.1   prekod 1  
                00f62b5c00004c000000014de7f073b1.2   prekre 1  
                00f62b5c00004c000000014de7f073b1.3   prekcf 1
Physical:       00f62b5ceb80c074                1   0  
                00f62b5ceb76311b                1   0  
                00f62b5ceb790075                1   0   
Total PPs:      309 
LTG size:       128 
HOT SPARE:      0 
AUTO SYNC:      0 
VG PERMISSION:  0 
SNAPSHOT VG:    0 
IS_PRIMARY VG:  0 
PSNFSTPP:       4352 
VARYON MODE:    ??????? 
VG Type:        0 
Max PPs:        32512
Mirror Pool Str n 
Sys Mgt Mode:   ??????? 
VG Reserved:    ??????? 
PV RESTRICTION: ??????? 
Infinite Retry: 2 
Varyon State:   0 
Disk Block Size 512
```

I need only these values out:

```
prekod
prekre
prekcf
```

I tried:

```
[root@hx042:/home/user1]$ lqueryvg -Atp hdiskpower13|sed -n -e '/Logical/,/Physical/ p'                
0516-1396 lqueryvg: The physical volume hdiskpower13, was not found in the
system database.
Logical:        00f62b5c00004c000000014de7f073b1.1   prekod 1  
                00f62b5c00004c000000014de7f073b1.2   prekre 1  
                00f62b5c00004c000000014de7f073b1.3   prekcf 1  
Physical:       00f62b5ceb80c074                1   0
```

and now I'm stuck because there is `Logical` in same line as first value I need, also there is this unavoidable error message which is not useful at all at this point which I also don't need.

Comment: to add: command `lqueryvg -Ap hdiskpower13` give same output but without value names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a smarter way to do this all in awk, but Guido's on the right track with sending stderr to /dev/null to get rid of the `0516-1396` message. Here's a pipeline that uses `sed` to print just the lines between "Logical:" and "Physical", then uses sed again to delete the trailing "Physical" line and to delete the "Logical:" text before then using awk to print the 2nd column:

```
lqueryvg -Atp hdiskpower13 | \
  sed -n '/^Logical:/,/^Physical:/ p' | \
  sed '/^Physical:/d; s/^Logical://' | \
  awk '{print $2}'
```

Here's an all-awk solution that is still pretty brute-force:

```
lqueryvg -Atp hdiskpower13 | \
  awk '/^Logical:/,/^Physical/ { 
    if (! /^Physical:/) { 
      gsub("Logical:", "", $0); 
      print $2 }}'
```

Comment: You're right… no `-E` option in AIX 

Comment: after playing around with lqueryvg a bit more, I would recommend: `lqueryvg -Lp hdiskpower13 | awk '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in prekod prekcf prekre; do lqueryvg -Atp hdiskpower13 | grep $i; done | sed 's/Logical://g' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' | awk '{print $2" "$3}'
```

Answer (score 0):

cut would also work I think, and it would be a little simpler, assuming the output is always going to be similar. For the specific output you quoted above:

```
grep 'prek*' |cut -w -f3
```